# Create one class used in all .cs files?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, class, xsd

I have to create a Windows service in C# that will exchange 6 types of XML messages between Oracle database and IBM MQ queue.

I have created the XML classes using XSD schemas and xsd.exe. However, I have noticed that some classes are duplicated in all 6 .cs files, as you can see below:

**PathCanceled.cs**:

```
 public partial class AdministrativeContactInformation
 {    
     private string nameField;
     private string addressField;
     private string eMailField;
     private string phoneNumberField;
     private string faxNumberField;
     private string freeTextFieldField;

     public string Name
     {
         get
         {
             return this.nameField;
         }
         set
         {
             this.nameField = value;
         }
     }
 (...)
```

**PathConfirmed.cs**:

```
 public partial class AdministrativeContactInformation
 {    
     private string nameField;
     private string addressField;
     private string eMailField;
     private string phoneNumberField;
     private string faxNumberField;
     private string freeTextFieldField;

     public string Name
     {
         get
         {
             return this.nameField;
         }
         set
         {
             this.nameField = value;
         }
     }
 (...)
```

And so on.

So, will it work if I'll just create one class `AdministrativeContactInformation` for all 6 .cs files?

Meaning that, I will create a .cs file named `AdministrativeContactInformation` that will contain the fields and and properties, then create an object of this class in every one of the 6 .cs files like this:

```
 public partial class PathCanceled
 {
     private AdministrativeContactInformation administrativeContactInformationField;
 }
(...)
```

Comment: Absolutely yes if the class is exactly the same in all files.  You should be geting a compiler error message if they are duplicates.  So if you are not getting a compiler error then they must be in different namespaces.  So you have to reference the common file by namespace:AdministrativeContactInformation

Comment: The classes were in the same namespace so, it makes sense now. I have created one class for every duplicates I had in those 6 .cs files. Thanks for the information, @jdweng!